# Oracle statement to get data in ascending order by month

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
select COLLABNAME,DATETIME,TOTALFLOWS,SUCCFLOWS,FAILEDFLOWS 
from TABLE_NAME WHERE  to_date(DATETIME, 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI') 
BETWEEN  trunc(sysdate-7) AND trunc(sysdate) 
AND COLLABNAME like 'COLLAB_NAME1';
```

This Oracle statement gives the data for the past 7 days. But when executed at the start of the month say 03042012 00:00 this populates the data in ascending order giving this months data first staring form say 01042012 00:00 to 03042012 23:00 and goes to the previous month data

What I need to get is the previous months data first followed by this months data i.e from 27032012 00:00 to 03042012 23:00 in ascending order of the month.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not really storing your dates in a varchar column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `order by COLLABNAME,to_date(DATETIME)` to the end of your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Works perfect now.